# Deleted a change set in eclipse, crisis ensues

Tags: eclipse, rtc, changeset

I wanted to remove a work item association to an outgoing change set and then associate it to a new work item.  However, I selected `Remove...` on the change set to remove the association, but it instead deleted all my code changes.  This is bad.  Can this be reverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a change set, that means it is a *committed* set of files.
If you selected "`Remove`" in the "`Related Artifacts / Associate Change Request`" dialog box, this shouldn't be an issue.

[image]

You always can test and make a second repo workspace, load that second repo workspace in a second local workspace and see if you get the change set back.
You can modify the flow target of your second repo workspace, and make it reference your first repo workspace, to see if you get that same change set in the "incoming" section of the "Pending Changes" view.